# C Private Variables Get and Set methods

Tags: c, private-members, private-methods

I am working in C, and have some variables that I don't want to be global, but I do want to have get and set methods for them that can be accessed "Globaly" outside of the file. I am used to doing this in Java, but C is very different in this manner. Basically I am looking for something that follows this pseudo Code, but I have not been able to find anywhere with examples that I might look at.

```
main.c
#include data.h
set(b);

datalog.c
#include data.h
get(b);

data.c
private int c;
set(b){
    c = b;
}
get(c){
    return c;
}
```

Comment: `C` does not have the notion of `private`. Maybe trying looking at `static` global variables.

Comment: Thus my question. How can I trick C?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Since `C` is not OOP (it's function oriented) you will have to work with functions and `struct`s or global variables.

Comment: C is not Java, so make sure there is a good reason for doing something non-canon before you do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You make the variable `static`. When a global variable is made `static`, its scope is restricted to the current file.

An example is as follows:

Filename: main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "header.h"

extern int get();
extern void set(int);

int main()
{
    set(10);
    printf("value = %d \n", get());   
    set(20);
    printf("value = %d \n", get());   
    set(30);
    printf("value = %d \n", get());   
    set(40);
    printf("value = %d \n", get());   
    return 0;
}
```

Filename: header.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get(void);
void set(int);
```

Filename: header.c

```
#include "header.h"

static int value = 0;

int get(void)
{
    return value;
}

void set(int new_value)
{
    value = new_value;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o main main.c header.h header.c 
$ ./main 
value = 10 
value = 20 
value = 30 
value = 40 
$
```

Comment: No need to declare `get()` and `set()` at the top of `main.c`. - This is why you created the header in the first place.

Comment: No need to include `stdio.h` in the header. - The code in the header does not use it.

Comment: why are you using the extern keyword?? makes no sense

Answer (score 10):

If you want private variables in c, there are a number of techniques that can approximate a private variable, but the C language actually doesn't have a "protection" concept that extends to private, public, protected (as C++ does).

C will show the *name* of any variable (it's a requirement in C) so you must approach it with the idea of information hiding the *type* of the variable (making dereferencing quite difficult).

One trick is to *define* the variable as an `void*` with the actual variable type being known in only one `.c` module.

```
 /* somefile.h */

 extern void* counter; 

 /* somefile.c */

 #include "somefile.h"

 int actualCounter = 0;
 void* counter = &actualCounter;

 /* otherfile.c */

 #include "somefile.h"

 // we can see "counter", but we cannot "use" it here; because we don't have access
 // to the real "hidden" type of "int".
```

A better method is to extend this idea using the `struct` keyword, and make pseudo-methods, like so

```
 /* person.h */

 struct s_person;

 typedef Person struct s_person;

 Person* new_Person(char* name);
 void delete_Person(Person* person);

 void Person_setName(Person* person, char* name);
 char* Person_getName(Person* person);

 /* person.c */

 struct s_person {
   char* name;
 };

 Person* new_Person(char* name) {
   Person* object = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(struct s_person));
   // duplicate the string for more security, otherwise constructor
   // could manipulate the "private" string after construction.
   object->name = strdup(name);
   return object;
 }

 void delete_Person(Person* person) {
   // some implementations pass a Person** to set the reference to 0
   // this implementation requires that the caller sets his own references to 0
   free(person->name);
   free(person);
 }

 void Person_setName(Person* person, char* name) {
   // free the old
   free(person->name);
   // duplicate the new to provide "out of simulated class" modification by malicious 
   // name setter.
   person->name = strdup(name);
 }

 char* Person_getName(Person* person) {
   // must return a copy, otherwise one can manipulate name
   // from reference provided by Person_getName(...);
   return strdup(person->name);
 }

 /* otherfile.c */

 #include "Person.h"

 /* Now we can hold Person "simulated objects", but we cannot */
 /* manipulate their "state" without using the C simulated object */
 /* methods */

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   Person* bob = new_Person("bob");
   printf("%s\n", Person_getName(bob));
   delete_Person(bob);
   // critical or we hold a pointer to freed memory.
   bob =  0;

   return 0;
 }
```

Techniques like this have several variants, one is to have a "public struct" with a void* pointer to the "private struct".  One is to include the "methods" as function pointers in the "public struct" (a step towards supporting polymorphism), one is to actually write a full and proper C++ type system which attempts to resolve things exactly as C++ would (class hierarchies, polymorphisim, late binding, information hiding, etc).

Basically, you can get some "object-oriented-ness" without too much work, but as you add more features of -ornamentation, you will add more glue code (until it *is* much simpler to actually use an object-oriented programming language).

Comment: Is it correct: typedef Person struct s_person; ? It would be: typedef struct s_person Person;, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can type:

```
static int c;
```

This way, the ".o" won't export the "c" variable.

Comment: So will I be able to access this from the get and set functions, but not directly? IE. Does `static` Change the scope of the variable?

Comment: `static` makes a global variable only visible inside the module it is declared. For example, if another module does `extern int c`, the linker will be unable to find "c".

Answer (score 2):

```
static int c;

int get(void) {
    return c;
}

int set(int n) {
    c = n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By your example, you can try using some `struct` with this information. A `struct` is like a `class` with only *public* member variables (i.e. no functions). So consider something as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _somestruct
{
  int c;
} theStruct;

int getC(theStruct* obj)
{
  if(obj == NULL)
    return -1;
  return obj->c;
}

void setC(theStruct* obj, int val)
{
  if(obj == NULL)
    return;
  obj->c = val;
}

int main()
{
  theStruct myStruct;
  setC(&myStruct, 5);
  printf("%d\n", getC(&myStruct));
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, `C` works only with objects and functions. But to get a global variable across all files, try `static int c = 0;`

The example above is nearly as close as you can possibly get to a "java-style" convention.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve on @RageD's answer by using function pointers:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

/********************************* MyClass.h **********************************/
// Typedef function pointers for usage clarity
typedef int (*GetInt)();
typedef void (*SetInt)();

typedef struct MyClass {
    int  Value;
    GetInt GetValue;
    SetInt SetValue;
} MyClass_t;

// Make the default class accessible to other modules
extern MyClass_t new_MyClass;

#endif    

/********************************* MyClass.c **********************************/
#include <stdio.h>

static int getValue(MyClass_t* obj){
    if(obj == NULL)
        return -1;

    return obj->Value;
}
static void setValue(MyClass_t* obj, int value){
    if(obj == NULL)
        return;

    obj->Value = value;
}

// Default "constructor" of MyClass 
MyClass_t new_MyClass = {0, &getValue, &setValue};

/*********************************** main.c ***********************************/
//#include "MyClass.h"

int main(){
    // Create a default instance of the class
    MyClass_t myClass = new_MyClass;

    // Call the private (static) Getter function --> Prints 0
    printf("%d\n", myClass.GetValue(&myClass));

    // Set the instance's value by the Setter function
    myClass.SetValue(&myClass, 9);

    // Prints 9
    printf("%d\n", myClass.GetValue(&myClass));

    return 0;
}
```